# Which is better- virtual env or docker?

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework

I am new to backend development and having some serious doubts which I am unable to clear.
I am going to work on some production level djangoRestFramework project and I learned it by creating a virtual environment. Now I have come across this Docker thing. Now I can say that this provided OS-level abstraction to our project.
But which I should use, docker or virtualenv? and why? The same project I want to deploy at someplace and what will be the benefits if I am using docker tr virtualenv?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtualenv only encapsulates Python dependencies. A Docker container encapsulates an entire OS.
With a Python virtualenv, you can easily switch between Python versions and dependencies, but you're stuck with your host OS.

With a Docker image, you can swap out the entire OS - install and run Python on Ubuntu, Debian, Alpine, even Windows Server Core.

There are Docker images out there with every combination of OS and Python versions you can think of, ready to pull down and use on any system with Docker installed.

https://hub.docker.com/_/python/

In simple terms, if you have the docker image of your code, you can install python and run it on any preferred environment. Which virtualenv doesn't support

With python virtual env you can only switch b/w python environments.

The best way would be write a docker file that uses virtal env , so you can switch diffrent version of python(if you have a requirement to handle multiple versions)

Answer (score 2):

With just a virtualenv it's lightweight, you build your environment quickly. But you will only have your python packages. The other tools or configuration (like database, caching etc.) should be done on the production server. This means that your local environment, CI environment and the production environment will have differences.
It's more difficult to [keep 12 factor dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity).

If you also use docker, then you will have the complete toolchain that could be common to all your environments, or at least, even if you do not use your docker image do develop, you will be able to run the production image locally to investigate behavior without impacting the production. And you will have no surprises (or very few) when moving a feature to production. You will also have a better security for your hosting server as your application will be encapsulated in a virtual OS.

The downside of docker is that it will be heavier both to build and to execute. And having an OS in another OS adds a level of complexity for you to manage.